# GridDB: How to handle 'Connection refused' error when connecting to GridDB database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, griddb

I'm trying to establish a connection to a GridDB database using Node.js and the griddb-node package. However, I keep encountering a 'Connection refused' error.

```js
const griddb = require('griddb-node');

try {
  const factory = griddb.StoreFactory.getInstance();
  const store = factory.getStore({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 31810,
    clusterName: 'defaultCluster',
    username: 'admin',
    password: 'admin'
  });

  // Perform database operations here

  store.close();
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Connection refused error:', error);
}
```

I have already verified that the host, port, cluster name, username, and password are correct. What could be causing this error, and how can I handle it?